# Защита от атак opencart

Tags: opencart, ddos, sql-injection

Магазин opencart версия 1.5.6. Каждый день приходят пустые заказы подобного вида без товаров с 0 ценой. Я как понимаю кто-то производит атаки.
Как можно закрыть дыру?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно смотреть каким образом делается атака и через что конкретно делается иньекция.... Так сказать сложно будет, но на форумах встречал. что нужен переезд на 2 версию.... В первой версии много уязвимостей было.

Answer (score 0):

Заказы приходят с формы/кнопки 'купить в один клик'. Об этом говорит комментарий к заказу. Это функционал out of the box, его допиливали либо это стороннее расширение, ocmod vqmod etc. Но не допилили. Перед сохранением заказа в бд, в контроллере должна пройти валидация полей полученных при оформлении заказа. В вашем случае валидация упущена недобросовестным разработчиком. Об это также говорит то, что в поле телефон, которое должно валидироваться на цифры и сопутствующие телефонам символы, попала строка string.

Та же можно предположить, что на момент получения этих заказов на сайте велась работа по внедрению функционала 'купить в один клик'. И разработчик постоянно тестировал функционал, но забывал очищать тестовые заказы.

Признаки атаки отсутствуют, т.к. в противном случае магазин получал бы подобные заказы ежесекундно вплоть до отказа.